# TableView not updating after button action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm relatively new to `swift`, and I'm trying to have a `view` that when it loads it will display some info on my `tableView`, then in the same `view` I have a `textfield` and a `button`

I want that the `button` performes an `action` that fetchs data from my server and updates my `tableView`

The problem is that the table is not being updated. How can I get the table to be updated?

CODE:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = 80;
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView();
    self.url = URL(string: "http://xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/api/produtos/listagem/favoritos/\(userID)");
    downloadJson(_url: url!);

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return produtos.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProdutoCell1") as? ProdutoCell else{
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    cell.lbl_nome_json.text = produtos[indexPath.row].nome;
    cell.lbl_categoria_json.text = produtos[indexPath.row].categoria;
    cell.lbl_loja_json.text = produtos[indexPath.row].loja
    //= produtos[indexPath.row].categoria;
   // cell.lbl_loja.text = produtos[indexPath.row].loja;


    if let imageURL = URL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/myslim/api/"+produtos[indexPath.row].url){

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL);

            if let data = data{
                let image = UIImage(data: data);
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imgView_json.image = image;
                }
            }
        }



    }

    return cell;
}
```

ACTION:

```
@IBAction func btn_search(_ sender: Any) {


    if self.txt_search.text == "" {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert",message: "Insira algo para pesquisar",preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

         self.present(alert,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }else{
        var pesquisa = String();
        pesquisa = self.txt_search.text!;
        let url2 = URL(string: "http://xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/api/produtos/listagem/favoritos/\(pesquisa)/\(self.userID)");

        downloadJson(_url: url2!);


    }



 func downloadJson(_url: URL){

    guard let downloadURL = url else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL){data, urlResponse, error in


        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else{
            print("algo está mal");
            return;
        }

        do{
            let decoder = JSONDecoder();
            let downloadedProdutos = try decoder.decode([ProdutoModel].self, from: data);
            self.produtos = downloadedProdutos
            print(downloadedProdutos);


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData();
                print("reload");
            }
        }catch{
            print("algo mal depois do download")
        }


        }.resume();
}
```

**EDIT**

I added some `print` to see how many object were being returned on my `downloadedProdutos` variable, on the `downloadJson()` function.
And at the `viewdidload` I get 2 object, its normal because I only have 2 Products, but when the `action` is done I still get 2 object although I should get only 1 object

Comment: Where are your `tableView`'s data source delegate methods?

Comment: I dont know if the methods you're referring are the ones that I added to my question @jake

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `tableView.dataSource = self` in `viewWillAppear` and it looks you missed func numberOfSections() -> Int method.
Add UITableViewDataSource like this 
`class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource` and it will recommend you required methods

Comment: The problem doesnt seem to be that, I already had the `delegate` and `dataSource` assigned to my `tableView`. And the method `numberOfSections()` causes the number of rows to duplicate